# How can I make this code faster in Python?

Tags: python, performance

```
input_numbers=list(map(int,input().split()))
sum_number=0

def my_gen(a):
    i=0
    while i <= a:
        yield i
        i += 1

for i in my_gen(input_numbers[0]):
    sum_number += i**input_numbers[1]

print(sum_number%1000000009)
```

I tried not using generator, but it was too slow.
so, tried again with generator and it was slow too.

How can I make this faster?//

More information:
My scoring bot is saying Time out.
and
(1<=input_numbers[0]<=1,000,000,000)
(1<=input_numbers[1]<=50)

& Numpy cant be used

Comment: Well, you can substitute your `my_gen()` function with `range()` to get started.

Comment: Why do you think looping over integers is the bottleneck here? The thing you should try to optimize is the repeated exponentiation. Your `my_gen` simply reimplements `range` poorly.

Comment: How large are the numbers? Where is the problem from?

Comment: You should probably mention in your question what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: What do you mean by "faster"? Do you have some test case that proves that this doesn't perform well enough to meet your requirements?

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica yes. I'm studying algorithm and.scoring bot give me 3 correct over 5. 2 is because of Time out.

Comment: What did the discussion on leetcode say? I'm pretty sure this is a problem there.

Comment: @MattDMo I already tried ```range()``` but it was slow yet.

Comment: @khelwood it's justkind of leetcode thing. I have to get ```sum_number%1000000009```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is slow because you're taking large exponents of large numbers. But the final output doesn't require the full sum, just the modulo. So you can apply basic modular arithmetic to keep the numbers in your calculation smaller while getting the same final answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) which will only require a loop over the power value (rather than the billion numbers from 0 to N).

```
from fractions import Fraction
from functools import lru_cache
@lru_cache()
def bernoulli(n,result=True): # optimized version
    A = [Fraction(1,n+1)]
    for j,b in enumerate(bernoulli(n-1,False) if n else []):
        A.append((n-j)*(b-A[-1]))
    return A[-1] if result else A

@lru_cache()
def comb(n,r):
    return 1 if not r else comb(n,r-1)*(n-r+1)//r

def powerSum(N,P):
    result = sum(comb(P+1,j) * bernoulli(j) * N**(P+1-j) for j in range(P+1))
    return (result / (P+1)).numerator
```

output:

```
powerSum(100,3) # 25502500

sum(i**3 for i in range(100+1)) # 25502500 (proof)

powerSum(1000000000,50)%1000000009 
# 265558322 in 0.016 seconds on my laptop

sum(i**50 for i in range(1000000000+1))%1000000009 
# 265558322 (proof in 16.5 minutes)
```

Comment: I wrote a version [using ints modulo 1000000009 instead of fractions](https://preview.tinyurl.com/y77dyqew) now, seems to be about 15 times faster on that large case (see benchmark results near the bottom there).

Comment: Thx alot! It is really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This is the **bad part** of problem: https://projecteuler.net/problem=429
But the **good parts** is to solve it yourself.